# Creating Webservice for retrieving value and updating it to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, json

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=^DJA&f=l1

returns value of Dow Jones.

I want to use this value of Dow Jones and update this value in my database.

How do I create such a webservice that checks for Dow Jones value every 1 minute and update the database?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you aren't going to **build** a web service.  Instead, you are going to **consume** a web service that someone else, Yahoo, already built.  You are what is known as the **service consumer**, and Yahoo is known as the **service provider**.

Here is some documentation from Yahoo's Developer Network that includes some sample code on making GET and POST requests using REST:

http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html

You could probably substitute your Yahoo Finance URL directly into the method shown in **C# GET SAMPLE 2**, and it should print the retrieved data to the console.

```
 public static void PrintSource(Uri address)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a webservice that checks the Dow Jones value and create cronjob that calls the webservice every x minutes. or you create a little program yourself that calls the webservice every x minutes.

A webservice only does it's work when it is called...

Comment: The OP won't "make a web service".  A web service exposes an interface for other systems to consume.  In this instance, the OP is building a "system" -- not a webservice -- that will "consume a web service".  Only if the OP exposes a REST API for other systems would his system then be called a web service.  This is just a minor syntactic detail; otherwise, your answer would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

At frist I think you have mistaken the meaning of a WebServce. The given URL might be a WebService. What you want is more like a "normal" service, which calls the WebService and stores the result into a database.

Doing this might be a simple task, depending on how you want to do it. Simplest would be, calling this URL, and storing the result as a simple string into your database. Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx) how to write a service, which is running in background on windows.

Comment: kun - I need to host this webservice on a shared hosting server. In that case, will a webservice running in background work?

Comment: @meetpd - I still think you're using the term "WebService" incorrectly.  Based on your question, you are consuming Yahoo's WebService.  To answer your question, your app could have a background process or thread that sleeps and every 1 minute wakes up to make a call to Yahoo Finance to retrieve the data.

Comment: @meetpd: In restricted environment where you can't install a Windows service or configure a scheduled job, you can "cheat" like explained here: http://www.codeproject.com/kb/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx